# Django and Jquery $.post function

Tags: jquery, python, django, backend, jquery-post

I am having trouble using the $.post() function with my views. I get no errors. I just get nothing from the jscript. It is either not reaching my view, or my view isn't calling my template.

my html snippet is

```
<textarea rows="4" cols"30" id="id_new_list" placeholder="Enter a gene list"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="parseList();">submit list</button>

<table id="id_list_table">
  <tr><td>{{ new_item_text }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

my jscript is:

```
var main = function(){   
    $('button').click(function(){
       var data = document.getElementById("id_new_list").value;
       $.post('lists/new',{item_text:data});   });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

my view is:

```
def home_page(request):   
    return render(request,'lists/home.html',{
        'new_item_text':request.POST.get('item_text',''),
    })  

def new_list(request):   
    data = request.POST.get('item_text','')  
    return render(request,'home.html',{
        'new_item_text': data,
    })
```

my url files:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'lists.views.home_page', name='home'),
    url(r'^lists/', include('lists.urls')),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^new$','lists.views.new_list',name='new_list'),
    )
```

I am not even getting the post to call my view I dont't think. My textarea and button were with form tags but I removed them and assumed it may be the csrf that was the issue.

Comment: Can you show error messages you got?

Comment: @dazedconfused no error. Just nothing posted to my view/html.

Comment: Can you see the POST to your URL inside Chrome's Network tab in developer tools when you click the button? Also, clicking on the button will call parseList() JS function.Does it exist? Why do you need that call as well as the event listener?

Comment: @MarioGudelj Sorry I am using the button action instead of the onclick call. Yes now that I removed the parseList on the button I get a 403 error on the post saying it's forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answer posted by `shellbye` may solve your problem, it also makes you vulnerable to CSRF attacks. Use `csrf_exempt` only if you know what you're doing. Do read [Django docs on CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/) to know more.

**Alternative to other answer**

You need to pass the CSRF token with every POST request.

HTML

```
<form ...>
    <!-- Set the CSRF token in the template -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea ... ></textarea>
</form>
```

The `{% csrf_token %}` template tag will generate a hidden input field in your template with a random value, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Sdf67Ghbsdf786afdsdf">
```

So, now you need to access this value and pass in the `$.post` parameters.

JS/jQuery

```
var main = function(){   
    $('button').click(function(){

        // get the value of CSRF token
        var CSRFtoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();

        var data = document.getElementById("id_new_list").value;

       $.post('lists/new', { 
           item_text: data,
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRFtoken
       });
    });
};
```

That's it. Make sure in the `$.post` parameters you don't name CSRF token other than `csrfmiddlewaretoken` because Django will access it only by this name.

**Yet another alternative**

In case you have to make many different AJAX `post` requests, you will need to pass CSRF token to each one of them. To save you that hassle, [here's a good approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) to do this once and for all.

Comment: I think this is it. I just found out how to do what you are saying ant it appears to work

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo where `cols"30"` should be `cols="30"`.

And you need `@csrf_exempt`() above your `new_list` like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def new_list(request):   
data = request.POST.get('item_text','')  
    return render(request,'home.html',{
        'new_item_text': data,
    })
```